# Replace Button in woocommerce by a clickable Image in PhP

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I sell online Gift Cards using Woocommerce on Wordpress. On the thank you page it displays the download image (containing the Gift Card Key) as a button.

I would like it to display the image itself to be downloaded in full size above the the download link.

[Screenshot of the Thank You Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggiI1.jpg)

**Here's the part that displays the download section in PHP:**

```
    <?php break;
                                case 'download-file' : ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $download['download_url'] ); ?>" class="woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file">
                                        <?php echo esc_html( $download['file']['name'] ); ?>
                                    </a>
```

Can you help me out plz?

Comment: What have you tried? Is `$download['download_url']` the image URL?

Comment: I'm new to PHP. I only know HTML, CSS and some java. So I tried googling some answers but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @YoumnaAlySobhy - in order to display the image we would need to know where the image is located.  If you don't know this, you can try printing the $download array using `<pre><?php print_r($download); ?></pre>`to see if the image is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. you have to `download` attribute to `<a>` tag

```
<?php
    break;
case 'download-file' : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $download['download_url'] ); ?>" 
      class="woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file" download>
    <?php echo esc_html( $download['file']['name'] ); ?>
    </a>
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply! but the code looks identical to the one i posted originally, right? What do u mean by "you have to download attribute to <a> tag"

Comment: you have to add `download`  attribute